# Internal Server Error on callback post

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httprequest

I'm trying test a login post, the endpoint exists and is ok but the response is always error. 
Detail: The request not hit in my endpoint, so the error 500 not is a error of my back-end.
Detail 2: In network tab in chrome the request not appear.

The error returns:

```
body:Object {error: "Object(...) is not a function"}
headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: }
status:500
statusText:"Internal Server Error"
url:"http://localhost:8080/"
```

My code is:

```
login(user, onsuccess?, onerror?): void {
    let url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}/`;
    this.httpClient.post(url, user, { headers: this.headers }).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.setLogin("test");
        if (onsuccess) {
          onsuccess(response);
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.setLogin("test");
        if (onerror) {
          onerror(error);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Internal Server Error Status: 500 is a server side error.

That means that something is perhaps wrong with the credentials the server is using to connect to a database, an exception is getting thrown, or the parameters you are sending to the route are incorrect.

It is impossible to tell which it is with certainty given only the front end code.

Comment: The request not hit in my api.

Comment: Try to make a POST call using POSTMAN or SOAPUI

Comment: It hit _some_ API, which returned the 500. If it did not hit the expected endpoint, then you have defined the target incorrectly somewhere. Maybe it's not supposed to be `localhost:8080` but some external webserver?

Comment: The request not fire, not appear in my network tab and my endpoint doesnt receive any request

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem...

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(TestMock, {
       passThruUnknownUrl: true
     }
```

I was using a mock to simulate an api for some situations, but this causa the problem and avoit my real requests be fire.